# How to convert HTML to text in Python?

Tags: python, html, text, beautifulsoup

I know there are a lot of answers on this question, but many of them are outdated, and when I found one that "worked", it did not work well enough.

This is my current code:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = "http://example.com"

req = requests.get(url)


html = req.text


PlainText = BeautifulSoup(html, 'lxml')
print (PlainText.get_text())
```

This is the output I get:

```
Example Domain




    body {
        background-color: #f0f0f2;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
        font-family: -apple-system, system-ui, BlinkMacSystemFont, "Segoe UI", "Open Sans", "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;

    }
    div {
        width: 600px;
        margin: 5em auto;
        padding: 2em;
        background-color: #fdfdff;
        border-radius: 0.5em;
        box-shadow: 2px 3px 7px 2px rgba(0,0,0,0.02);
    }
    a:link, a:visited {
        color: #38488f;
        text-decoration: none;
    }
    @media (max-width: 700px) {
        div {
            margin: 0 auto;
            width: auto;
        }
    }




Example Domain
This domain is for use in illustrative examples in documents. You may use this
    domain in literature without prior coordination or asking for permission.
More information...
```

This is the output I want:

```
Example Domain
This domain is for use in illustrative examples in documents. You may use this domain in literature without prior coordination or asking for permission.

More information...
```

How can I get only the text I can read printed out from a website?

Comment: What do you mean by plain text?

Comment: `get_text()` return a string. What return type are you looking for?

Comment: Prayson W. Daniel: I mean the text that are shown on the page, and not all other kind of stuff. For example when using this script on a wikipedia page, this is one of the sentences in the output: "Indian cultural history spans more than 4,500 years.[346] During the Vedic period (c. 1700 – c. 500 BCE)"         That is not plain text.

Comment: Cyzanfar: What do you mean by "return type"?

Comment: Your question is still not clear, would you explain what do you mean by plain text?! can you give us examples of how html text looks like and what you want as output?!

Comment: **HTML:::**   In England and Wales, a national <a href="/wiki/Amenity_society" title="Amenity society">amenity society</a> must be notified of any work to a listed building which involves any element of demolition.<sup id="cite_ref-2" class="reference"><a href="#cite_note-2">&#91;2&#93;</a></sup>

**OUTPUT:::**   In England and Wales, a national amenity society must be notified of any work to a listed building which involves any element of demolition.

Comment: `"Indian cultural history spans more than 4,500 years.[346] During the Vedic period (c. 1700 – c. 500 BCE)" That is not plain text.` What about this is not plain text?

Comment: I am sorry. I am definitely not explaining well enough. By plain text I mean the text that are shown on the website. For example "[346]" is not shown on the website. I want only the text you can read on the website printed out

Comment: Using Soup.text you won't get plain text.Rather you will get all tag and content details what beautiful soup retrieve.What you need to do, You need to find those elements you are looking after to print text.

Comment: Always Post your Html or url and mentioned your expected output.So it won't make confusion to other contributor.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should work, as long as the "Plain text" part doesn't contain the character '}'.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = "http://example.com"

req = requests.get(url)


html = req.text


PlainText = BeautifulSoup(html, 'lxml')

text = Plaintext.get_text()
split = text.split('}')
withoutCss = split[len(split) - 1]



print (withoutCss)
```

Comment: Yeah. It worked, but not on other links.. I tried with a wikipedia link, and it failed. I just got this output: );

Answer (score 0):

Here is a python program that uses a function to remove everything between the < tags and the > tags, and returns just the text that is not between these tags.

```
def striphtmltags(s):
    b=True
    r=''
    for i in range(0, len(s)):
        if(s[i]=='<'): b=False
        if(b): r+=s[i]  
        if(s[i]=='>'): b=True
    return(r.strip())   

html="<html><body><h1>this is the header</h1>this is the main body<font color=blue>this is blue</font><h6>this is the footer</h6></body></html>"
text=striphtmltags(html)

print("text:", text)
```

This produces:

```
text: this is the headerthis is the main bodythis is bluethis is the footer
```